# xmpp file share

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, fileshare

I want to do file sharing using XMPP.I have gone through all XEP protocols provided like XEP-0096,0095,0060 and many more but cant find out proper way to go ahead! please guide me with that.using XEP-0096 I am at that state where on reception side another user gets accept/decline popup.but when he accepts some error occurs which I can't identify.

Answer (score 2):

Some mechanisms are in following XEPs, but they both are Deferred

- [Link1](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0135.html)
- [Link2](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0214.html)